# Transact-SQL Sub Query

Tags: sql, excel, t-sql

I'm struggling to find the logic of how to accomplish a sub query, or at least that's what I think is required! I'll show what I have:

```
SELECT  CH.SFA, 
        convert(datetime, RE.START_DATE, 103) AS 'START DATE', 
        Count(Distinct CH.CHNO) AS 'TOTAL CH', 
        Count(CH.STATUS) AS 'COMPLETED CH', 
        count(distinct  CH.CHNO +  CH.STATUS) As 'COMPLETED CH2'
FROM CUSTOMER.dbo. CH  CH, CUSTOMER.dbo.RE RE
WHERE 
      RE.SFA = CH.SFA
GROUP BY  
      CH.SFA, RE.START_DATE
```

What I am trying to do is where I have COMPLETED CH2 I need to specify that it ends with a C, the Status Column is either blanks or C's and by doing a distinct count of CHNO and C together give me the result I need but I cannot for the life of me find out how to write it!

I am using Microsoft Query to take the data from its source straight into the Excel spreadsheet.

Many thanks for taking a look.

Comment: What isn't working?  Wrong result, or long execution time?  Something else?

Comment: The query is fine but the count(distinct  CH.CHNO +  CH.STATUS) As 'COMPLETED CH2' needs to have its own WHERE Clause, Where CH.STATUS is a 'C'

Comment: As a side note I suggest using an `INNER JOIN` rather than the old `FROM` multiple tables with a `WHERE` clause format.

Comment: Got it.  Yes, a subquery would do that.  Gimme a minute and I'll answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Been ages since I've used MS Query so I'm fuzzy on syntax, but this is the general idea of how to write a subquery containing a `WHERE` clause and an aggregation to get you started:

```
SELECT  
    CH.SFA, 
    convert(datetime, RE.START_DATE, 103) AS 'START DATE', 
    Count(DISTINCT CH.CHNO) AS 'TOTAL CH', 
    Count(CH.STATUS) AS 'COMPLETED CH',
    CCH.COMPLETED_CH2 AS 'COMPLETED CH2'
FROM CUSTOMER.dbo.CH CH
INNER JOIN CUSTOMER.dbo.RE RE
    ON RE.SFA = CH.SFA
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT SFA, COUNT(DISTINCT CH.CHNO) AS COMPLETED_CH2
    FROM CUSTOMER.dbo.CH
    WHERE STATUS = 'C'
    GROUP BY SFA
) AS CCH
    ON RE.SFA = CCH.SFA
GROUP BY CH.SFA, RE.START_DATE
```

Comment: Thanks very much - really appreciate the effort - will try and mark as correct shortly (hopefully :0)

Comment: You're welcome.  Check my edit ... I changed `SSH.COMPLETED_CH` to `CCH.COMPLETED_CH` in the main `SELECT`.

Comment: I'm getting invalid column name 'COMPLETED_CH'

Comment: I've removed the comma at the end of the FROM Line and also changed CHINO to CHNO but still get the invalid column name 'COMPLETED_CH' issue. Didn;t want to edit your code to the changes mentioned here in case incorrect.... Thanks

Comment: If it works, it's correct and you should change it.  You're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

if you just want to know count of records where `CH.STATUS = 'C'` than add another `COUNT` statement with `CASE` logic.

`COUNT(CASE WHEN CH.STATUS = 'C' then 1 else null end) as 'COMPLETED CH2'`

when combining `COUNT` and `CASE` statement remember to have `NULL` for `ELSE` statement, otherwise all rows will be counted.

as an alternative you can do it with a `SUM`

`SUM(CASE WHEN CH.STATUS = 'C' then 1 else 0 end) as 'COMPLETED CH2'`

Comment: Thanks for the info SaUce, however the calculation is based upon another column having data in it and thus requiring a sub query. I can certainly utilise the above somewhere else though - Thanks :0)